# Select particular not grouped column from grouped set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

The topic might be a little bit unclear but I couldn't describe in a single sentence what I want to achieve.

Say I have a table that is (columns)

```
id      INT     PK
name    VARCHAR
date    DATE
```

I have a grouping select

```
select
    name,
    max(date)
from table
group by name
```

that gives me a name and the latest date.

*What is the easiest way to join the id column to the current aggregated result set with the id value where the date was the maximum?*

Let me explain what my goal is with an example:

The table is filled with the data as follows

```
id      name        date
1       david       2012-12-12
2       david       2013-12-02
3       patrick     2014-01-02
4       patrick     2012-11-11
```

and by my query I'd like to get the following result

```
id      name        date
2       david       2013-12-02
3       patrick     2014-01-02
```

Notice that all the records for `name = 'david'` are aggregated and the maximum date is selected. How to get the row id for this maximum date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, name, date
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, date, 
        row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) rn
    FROM yourtable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/446b5/2)

Another option is to join the table back to itself using the `MAX()` aggregate.  This option could potentially result in ties if multiple id/name combinations share the same max date:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date
FROM yourtable t
    JOIN (SELECT name, max(date) maxdate
          FROM yourtable
          GROUP BY name) t2 on t.name = t2.name AND t.date = t2.maxdate
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/446b5/3)

Comment: I actually asked because I hoped there was a built-in way to join another not-grouped column corresponding to the aggregated with `max` date value. Since you didn't post any solution like this, I assume there's none. Anyway thanks for your time and making things clear!